# Overriding Form Constructor with Pre-existing Data Makes Form Un-editable

Tags: python, django, django-forms, forms

I want to override a form that I have created with existing data if the user's profile exists so that the user can edit the data they may have already submitted. My code overrides the the init method of the Form, but when the form is rendered the form has the text, but it not editable. I need it to be editable.

The form code looks as below:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    aboutme = forms.CharField( widget=forms.Textarea )
    aboutmeprivate = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    interestsprivate = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProfileForm, self)
    self.aboutme = kwargs.pop('aboutme')
    self.aboutmeprivate = kwargs.pop('aboutmeprivate')
    self.interestsprivate = kwargs.pop('interestsprivate')
```

The call looks like:

```
form = ProfileForm(aboutme=exisitingprofile.aboutme, aboutmeprivate=exisitingprofile.aboutmeprivate, interestsprivate=exisitingprofile.interestsprivate)
```

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give like this, the super should come after the self.your_field and also you are missing the __init there

```
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    aboutme = forms.CharField( widget=forms.Textarea )
    aboutmeprivate = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    interestsprivate = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.aboutme = kwargs.pop('aboutme')
        self.aboutmeprivate = kwargs.pop('aboutmeprivate')
        self.interestsprivate = kwargs.pop('interestsprivate')
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

By not editable you mean to say that the field is not clickable?

Comment: I will try that later. I think I did try, but when I did that the fields were completely blank. I will look again though.

Comment: I have tried exactly as above and this will give me empty fields, if I remove the __init__(*args, **kwargs) from the end of the last line then I get the form completed with the details, but un-editable. I have also tried adding "request.POST" as one of the parameters I am passing, but that makes no difference.

Comment: To answer above on "not editable", by this, I mean that the form shows the text that would go in the fields, but they are read only.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to modify the call to the form from the view as below:

```
            form = ProfileForm(initial={'aboutme': exisitingprofile.aboutme,
                                    'aboutmeprivate' : exisitingprofile.aboutmeprivate,
                                    'interestsprivate' : exisitingprofile.interestsprivate })
```

I didn't need to override the constructor.